# Bitwise AND operator doesn't work as expected

Tags: php, binary, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

I use binary code to handle my overwrites in my database, but now I need to lookup about the rules are match or not match to this i have follow rules.

- 1 = unlock title
- 2 = unlock desc
- 4 = unlock price
- 8 = unlock stock

When I use php I try to use it like MySQL match:

```
$overwirtes = 5;

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & decbin(1) )
{
    // unlock title
}

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & decbin(2) )
{
    // unlock desc
}

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & decbin(4) )
{
    // unlock price
}

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & decbin(8) )
{
    // unlock stock
}
```

What I expect it's title and price are unlock and desc and stock are lock, but something go wrong and php will not accept binary like MySQL, can somebody tell me what I do wrong here, I'm still new to work on Binary code as rules.

Comment: What is the code in the if statements?

Comment: its array like ( 1 or 0 ) its only to illustrate my problem, :)

Comment: Remove the `decbin()` calls from the 1,2,4,8 and everything should work fine

Comment: Hmmm wird, can you explain me why this will work? i have tested it, and its look like its working but why? its make no sanse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You run into a "funny" problem. And this is that [`decbin()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php) returns a string.

Now if both operands of the [bitwise AND](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php) operator are strings the operation is preformed with the [ASCII values](http://www.asciitable.com/) of the strings.

Also a quote from the manual which shows this too:

> If **both operands** for the **&, | and ^ operators** are **strings**, then the **operation** will be performed on the **ASCII values** of the characters that make up the strings and the result will be a string. In **all other cases**, **both operands will be converted to integers** and the **result** will be an **integer**.

So what does that mean in your specific example?

Let's take the second if statement:

```
$overwirtes = 5;
decbin($overwirtes) & decbin(2)
```

Well technical this should be evaluated as followed:

```
0000 0101    (5)
0000 0010    (2)
---------- &
0000 0000    = 0 (FALSE)
```

But since **both** operands are string the bitwise AND takes the ASCII values of both strings which here would be this:

```
0011 0101    (53)  
0011 0010    (50) 
---------- &
0011 0000    = "48" (TRUE)
```

So that's why all conditions in your code evaluates as TRUE.

But now how to solve this? Simple, just change 1 operand of the operation to an integer. So you can just remove the `decbin()` call from 1, 2, 4, 8.

You can also then see in the manual(quote above) when 1 operand isn't a string (here an integer) that both operands gets implicit casted to an integer. And you also receive an integer.

So your code should look something like this:

```
$overwirtes = 5;

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & 1)
{
    // unlock title
}

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & 2)
{
    // unlock desc
}

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & 4)
{
    // unlock price
}

if ( decbin($overwirtes) & 8)
{
    // unlock stock
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this friendly explain, now i understand but still confuse over PHP dont convert it to "bin" when i say it, but what you say its working as i shut be so its perfect, thanks a lot :)

Comment: Doesn't this mean that `$overwirtes` will be converted back to an integer by interpreting its bits as *decimal* digits? That would be very wrong. Why convert it to string in the first place?

Comment: @harold Yes, I just wanted to show that at least on of the operands has to be an integer